# adding an object to an empty <a/> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting

```
 var a = $("<a/>");
```

then I'm trying to fill this empty variable with the contents of an object, set to variable 'obj'

```
obj = {
 Name: " Ben",
 number: 666,
}
```

I have tried to append a using the various methods

```
a.append(obj);
a.append("("+obj+")");
```

but if I then do:

```
console.log(a)
```

there is no way to tell if the object is now in the link tag. If I look in the console on the site I can see

```
([object Object])
```

rather than the contents. Am I missing something?

Comment: What result are you expecting? Something like `<a>Name: Ben, number: 666,</a>`?

Comment: yes, some way to know that information is there

Answer (score 3):

By just appending the object it is implicitly coerced to a string, hence you see `[Object object]`.

You need to convert the object to a legible string manually. You can do that by using `JSON.stringify()`, like this:

```js
var $a = $('<a href="#"/>').appendTo('body');
var obj = {
  Name: " Ben",
  number: 666
};

$a.text(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use property of object
like below

```
var a = $("<a/>");
obj = {
  Name: " Ben",
  number: 666,
 }

a.text(obj.Name + ' ' + obj.number);
```